# Не подсвечивает синтаксис Unity. В чем проблема?

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Скачал нужные пакеты, но синтаксис Unity не подсвечивает.

[image: Настройки]

[image: Visual studio]

[image: Пакеты]

Comment: Можно проверить, что вы установили VisualStudio  именно к той версии Unity, на которой и запускаете проект, хотя, по-моему, это  VisualStudio распространяется на все версии... Может быть, есть еще какие-то варианты ExternalScriptEditor? А вообще, насколько я знаю, чтобы VisualStudio подсвечивал синтаксис для Unity нужно не в VisualStudio скачивать (докачивать) расширения `Разработка игр с помощь Unity` и `Разработка классических приложений .NET`, а скачивать их в САМОМ Unity при установке определенной версии unity (там должна быть самая верхняя галочка).

Comment: @МаксимФисман спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в ExternalScriptEditor
Действия:
Открываете Visaul studio через Unity
В диспетчере задач, ищите расположения фаила и копируйте путь, в ExternalScriptEditor
выбираете Browse и вставляйте путь до devenv.exe
Готово!